# Why model trains slower on GCP than on my local machine?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I'm using tensorflow-cloud and train a 3D voxel CNN.
My local machine: NVIDIA GeForce RTX  2080 Ti 11GB, Intel Core i7 3GhZ, 32 GB RAM
This is my machine config on tfc:

```
tfc.MachineConfig(cpu_cores=8, memory=30, accelerator_type=tfc.AcceleratorType.NVIDIA_TESLA_T4, accelerator_count=1),
```

To me this looks comparable. However, the training job takes 2-3 times as long as on my local machine. Do I share the cloud machine with other training jobs?
Also the the job might be IO limited, on my local machine my training set (12GB) is stored on a SSD.
Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Hard to say with so many varying factors. Is your code able to run on a distributed setup of GPUs? Do you run a larger batch size on GCP? If you have the same batch size then I do believe the RTX 2080 is actually the stronger card because it has [368 tensor cores and 10.07 TFLOPS (FP32) performance](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-rtx-2080.c3224) compared to [320 tensor cores and 8.141 TFLOPS (FP32) performance](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/tesla-t4.c3316) of the Tesla T4.

Comment: Same batch size. The 2 TFLOPs advantage should not explain a factor 2-3. The MachineConfig does not say anything about SSD - if it's on a HD this would explain the difference. The tfc.MachineConfig does not specify the disk....

Comment: Yeah, with an HDD the bottleneck is most likely IO operations. But if you have a large model size then the majority of the time should be spent doing forward and backwards passes on the GPU and not loading batches from the disc and onto the memory of the GPU. Have you checked that [CUDA/GPU is available](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available)?

Comment: GCP may use the name 'core' for a 'virtual core' or 'VCPU', which mean CPU threads https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms. If your PC has 8 physical cores it may have twice more threads.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is easy: our training was CPU limited due to online augmentation code implemented in python. Turns out, the gcp machines have strong GPUs but compared to our local machines weak CPUs.

Increasig the number of cpu_cores to a higher number (32 or 64) helps, but also makes things very expensive, since also the number of GPUs has to be increased (2 or 4).

The solution is probably to port the python code to tensorflow / CUDA.